# Destabilizing subsheaf: length of $0$ dimensional subscheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

I have a very specific question (quite elementary, sorry!)

Let $G$ be a rank $2$ torsion free sheaf on an algebraic surface $X$ (normal maybe?)

Let $L\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z$ be a Gieseker destabilizing subsheaf of $G$ where $Z$ is a $0$ dimensional subscheme.

> Is it true that $l(Z)<\frac{1}{2}c_2(G)$ where $l(Z)$ is the length of $Z$?

If not, can we at least say $\leq$ or something? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try comparing Hilbert polynomials?

Comment: @Sasha Yeah, I made a mistake in my calculation of the Hilbert polynomials earlier today. I think for the case I'm thinking about this is quite easy. Maybe I will delete this post.